# SELECT records MySQL: between date + 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I want to SELECT all records between two dates plus one record before and one record after that date? All records are ordered by date.

Comment: Is it a date or a datetime?  One record before/after a date time could be sub-seconds apart...needs to be made clear here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  (select * from t where date < start_date order by date desc limit 1)
  union (select * FROM t WHERE date between start_date and end_date)
  union (select * from t where date > end_date order by date asc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a union combined with the limit statement.  Something like what's below (untested, don't have access to mysql).

```
(select column from table where datefield > startdate and datefield < stopdate)
union
(select column from table where datefield < startdate order by datefield desc limit 1)
union
(select column from table where datefield > stopdate order by datefield limit 1)
```

This will give you the next row regardless of where it falls date-wise.

Thanks for syntax fix, ponies.

Comment: Based on the OPs wording, this seems right, but wonder if it was intentional to **leave out** the start/stop dates, or should the range be >= and <= ???

Comment: MySQL error 1064 - syntax error, because you can't use LIMIT or ORDER BY in a UNION, without first putting such in brackets/parenthasis for LIMIT/ORDER BY that is to be applied to a specific query in the UNION statement.  Also, UNION will remove duplicates - UNION ALL will not, and be faster for it.

Comment: So each statement into parentheses?

Comment: ORDER BY  should be 'datefield' instead of startdate/stopdate, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions to add or subtract values, like this:

```
select * from table where field1 < ADDDATE(  CURTIME() , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) where there are some examples.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERAL -1 DAY) 
                AND DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: +1: Correct, and will use an index if one exists on the `date` column.

Comment: Wouldn't this include **all** records on prev/next dates?  Thought the OP only wanted one record on each end...

Comment: It doesn't sound like he's asking for the date + 1 day.  I read it as he's asking for the records in the date, plus the next record, regardless of whether it's the next day or a year from his end date.